# Joomla page title (shown twice)

Tags: joomla, head, page-title

I'm having a problem with the title of my pages in Joomla 2.5.2.

For example, my site name would be: "The big PROJECT" and I set that the parameter "Include site name in page title" to "before".

On my menu items settings, in "Page Display Options", I set "Browser Page Title" to "Home". When I set it with an uppercase "H", the title displays like this:
"The big PROJECT - The big PROJECT - Home". If I set with a lowercase "h" ("home"), then the page title appears as "The big PROJECT - home" without showing two times the site name.

Is there something I missed? Why is the title displaying the site name twice when there's a capitalized menu title?

Thanks,
Jeremie

Comment: Is this a vanilla installation of Joomla! ? What template are you using, and is it still an issue if you upgrade to the latest version?

Comment: Does it do it with any other words or just Home with a capital H?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the plugin used for the drop-down menu. I removed that plugin and tested with the normal menu, and everything was fine.

It really took me a while to figure out, as I was trying to tweak and tweak to make it work.

Hope that can help someone... Always test the plugins!

Jeremie